# Chrome extension uninstall URL not working in all cases

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I track my extension uninstalls using the method chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL

It has been working fine for months but recently I noticed that if I remove the extension from the Chrome Webstore page (e.g. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/{ext_name}/{ext_id}), then the uninstall URL is not opened.

Has something changed in the runtime API? Is this now expected behaviour?

Comment: Sounds like WebStore forgot to handle setUninstallURL. Report it on https://crbug.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug was reported by the original question author and is tracked at [issue 900554](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=900554).

Judging from the fact that it required a bisect, it's a bug in Chrome's integration with Web Store (since Chrome 67), not Web Store itself.

Comment: Marking as answered, bug was picked up by Chrome's team